# Is it possible to perform Full Outer join in Spring Data JPA, when the underlying MariaDB database does not support Full Outer Join?

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am working on a `FULL OUTER JOIN` query on the same table(`self full outer join`), but my underlying database `MariaDB` does not support the operation. The query also involves where clause as well. Is there a way in Spring Data `JPA` to accomplish the same?

Comment: Why would you ever need a self-full outer join?

Comment: Needed as part of a requirement.

Comment: "requirement" or homework?  If the former, I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

No Hibernate can only do what the underlying database is able to do.

Comment: Long answer is, under the cover,  JPA data gets translated to a native SQL query based on the dialect(mysql, oracle, h2..etc), declared in props-file :)

Answer (score 0):

If Spring can do a `UNION`, then it can simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

```
( SELECT ... FROM a )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... FROM b LEFT JOIN a ON ... WHERE a.id IS NULL )
```